# Displaying duplicate row numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I joined a table to itself to find duplicate rows

```
select a.data, a.rowNumber, b.rowNumber
from DuplicateRows as a
join DuplicateRows as b 
on
a.data = b.data and a.Id != b.Id
group by a.data, a.rowNumber, b.rowNumber
```

This query gives the results like

```
"content" | 1 | 2
"content" | 1 | 6
"content" | 2 | 1
"content" | 2 | 6 
...and so on
```

Howcome I rewrite it to have results formed like

```
"content" | 1 | 2, 6
```

**EDIT**

I think the question should be a little bit corrected. 
You see I don't want to get the inversed result, I mean I just want to get 
one entry

```
`1 -> 2, 6`
```

not

```
`1 -> 2, 6 and `2 -> 1, 6`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `a.Id != b.Id`, I'd suggest `b.Id > a.Id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your latest edit, I think this is what you'll be needing:

```
SELECT a.data, a.a, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT b.a)
FROM TableName as a
JOIN TableName as b 
    ON a.data = b.data AND a.a < b.a
GROUP BY a.data
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cbc13/6)

## PS

I used(and modified) John Woo's table a little bit.

## EDIT

A relatively better results from this query:

```
SELECT a.data, MIN(a.rowNumber), GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT b.rowNumber)
FROM DuplicateRows AS a
JOIN DuplicateRows AS b 
  ON a.data = b.data AND a.rowNumber < b.rowNumber
GROUP BY a.data
```

The fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/898026/6).

Answer (score 4):

use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT  a.data, 
        a.rowNumber, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.rowNumber)
FROM    DuplicateRows AS a
        INNER JOIN DuplicateRows AS b 
            ON  a.data = b.dataAND a.Id != b.Id
GROUP BY a.data, a.rowNumber
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bee43/1)

Answer (score 1):

try GROUP_CONCAT function in  mysql

```
select a.data, a.rowNumber, group_concat(b.rowNumber)
from DuplicateRows as a
join DuplicateRows as b 
on
a.data = b.data and a.Id != b.Id
group by a.data, a.rowNumber, b.rowNumber
```