# How to find duplicate rows in a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667035/mysql-duplicate-rows)
>   [Displaying duplicate row numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890028/displaying-duplicate-row-numbers)

Can anybody tell me how to find duplicate rows in a table if there is not any primary key column in the table?

Comment: we are not psychic here. Please add more details on your question.

Answer (score 1):

For `Table` with columns `Field1, Field2`:

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2
FROM Table
GROUP BY FIELD1, FIELD2
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```